# Check if link exist, and if redirect 301 follow redirect and check again, and if is the same domain

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to check if some old links are still valid:

I use:

```
response = requests.get(url).status_code
  if response == 200:
    return True
```

But I have this cases:

1. the url redirects to https or www, keeping the domain
2. the url redirects to a region version, example url/en, keeping the domain
3. the url redirect to a different domain (like a hosting page, bad domain etc)

I want to follow 1,2 and if they return 200, `return True`,
but I want to `return False` if the domain change , case 3

I figure out how to extract the domain:

```
"{0.scheme}://{o.netloc}//".format(urlsplit(url))
```

but, I need to follow 301 redirects.

Comment: What have you tried so far to check for redirects?

Comment: `r.history ` try using this one.

Comment: `requests` will follow the redirects and you can get the final url by `response.url`. Also you can limit max_redirects by `session.max_redirects` or no redirects `get(allow_redirects = False)`